# SignalR integration using Swift in ios using Cocoapods - Error during negotiation request

Tags: swift, signalr

I am working on integrating SignalR in swift ios.I followed the steps as it is in the following link https://github.com/adamhartford/SwiftR to integrate cocoapods..

I could not able to connect to sever.
I am being ended up with error.

```
Error: Optional({
message = "Error during negotiation request.";})
```

I cross checked with version number i am using for swift is 2.2.0 and also for javascript 2.2.0

Here I observed that the code downloaded from git is working fine with my ULR where as the code written by my is giving error though i used the same code.Please let me know where i am missing.

Note: The same url is working fine for andorid.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this yet? I'm experiencing the same issue here.

Comment: Error during negotiation request. Some Times causes form server also.
Ask your backend guys to add CORDS in their code.
In your Xcode check the plist and add AppTransportSecurity True.
This changes has solved my issue.
Good Luck

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Will definitely try your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Just update your pod file like this and install your pods. As long as you are not targeting a specific version of a pod

```
target '<YOUR PROJECT TRAGET>' do
use_frameworks!

target '<YOUR PROJECT TEST TRAGET>' do
   inherit! :search_paths
   pod 'SwiftR'
end

target '<YOUR PROJECT UI TEST TRAGET>' do
inherit! :search_paths
pod 'SwiftR'
end

end
```